# How to use WebClient.UploadFileAsync to upload files and POST Params as well?

Tags: c#

I am using `WebClient.UploadFileAsync` to upload local files to a web server and I would also like to pass some parameters with the post as well. I would like to send a few fields that will tell the PHP code on the server specific locations on where to save the uploaded files.

I tried to put the fields directly into the url, for example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/upload.php?field1=test");
client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "POST", "c:\test.jpg");
```

The PHP code returns false for `isset($_REQUEST['field1'])`.

Thank you for any suggestions.

[NOTE: this question was also asked in very similar format for vb.net a while back, but it did not get any answers,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615507/pass-post-params-to-webclient-uploadfileasync)

Comment: You should describe what's going wrong... "this did not help" is not enough information.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. The question has been edited.

Comment: Okay, so what happens if you look via Wireshark to see what the network traffic is like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72232/Csharp-File-Upload-with-form-fields-cookies-and-he.aspx) goes into detail about what is needed to accomplish posting of fields while uploading files using WebClient.

> Unfortunately, most file upload scenarios are HTML form based and may
>   contain form fields in addition to the file data. This is where
>   WebClient falls flat. After review of the source code for WebClient,
>   it is obvious that there is no possibility of reusing it to perform a
>   file upload including additional form fields.
>
> So, the only option is to create a custom implementation that conforms
>   to rfc1867, rfc2388 and the W3C multipart/form-data specification that
>   will enable file upload with additional form fields and exposes
>   control of cookies and headers.

Answer (score 0):

WebClient's UploadFile is designed to send only a file (as byte[]) as part of request. From my understanding, UploadFile method closes the request stream after writing the binaries.

In your scenario, you actually request is has two parts 1. file as byte[] 2. the file name as string.

To do this, you have to use HttpWebRequest or any other high level class capable of creating request.

Refer to the post http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx?display=Print
which does a similar job

Answer (score -1):

I would look into using the QueryString property of the WebClient to set the value of field1 (as well as any other QueryString parameters to the request).

```
NameValueCollection query = new NameValueCollection();
query.Add("field1", "test");
client.QueryString = query;
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.querystring(v=VS.100).aspx