# Upload object containing files via web-services

Tags: json, winforms, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am programming a web-service with Asp.Net MVC4. I am using WinForms for the Client. 
I have implemented a SearchController that is able to return a list of Items.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Shared.Item> ByTag(string search)
{
    ModelDbContext db = ModelDbContext.Current;
    db.Items.Load();
    //find some items....
    return itemList;
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Item>> SearchByTag(string tag)
        {

            client.BaseAddress = serviceAdress;
            var getStuffCall=client.GetAsync("Search/ByTag/" + tag);
            var r=getStuffCall.ContinueWith(
                t =>t.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode? (t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Item>>().Result):new List<Item>()
                );
            return r;
        }
```

This works fine. Now I would like to upload also an Item to the server. The problem is, that my type Item is structured and also contains a list of files and a list of pictures. As far as I understood, this does not work with a json-object. Or can I somehow wrap/encode my files and pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WinForms, you're likely going to want to use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx), which allows you to POST multi-part forms to the server.

Just remember that HTTP wasn't really designed for file transport, so just consider that if you have a whackload of files to push.

Finally on the controller you're going to want to do something like this: [How To Accept a File POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi)

There are a couple of relevant links there and some good samples.

Hope this helps a little more.

Comment: Thanks again. I looked at WebClient, but only found methods to upload a single file, string, byte-array or key-value pairs. In here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257957/how-to-use-webclient-uploadfileasync-to-upload-files-and-post-params-as-well they say that it not possible with w WebClient. Or has that changed?

Comment: No, it looks like you're right. But that doesn't stop you from making multiple requests (1 for each file). As a last resort, you could ZIP the files up.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write a bunch of code yourself, or go with a jQuery plugin such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/about/). The reason for this is that XMLHttpRequest does not allow encoding/uploading of files through Ajax. This plugin uses several known work-arounds/solutions/failovers to make it work for you.

With this in place, you could consider making two calls, one for your object, and one for the files/images that you wish to push to the server.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I am using WinForms for the Client, I cannot use Uploadify. Sorry that I forgot to mention the Winforms.